# Java - non blocking SocketChannel for device control, general approach

Tags: java, sockets, nio, nonblocking

I'm looking for a good way to control an external device over its TCP/IP interface.
The device is controlled by command strings and answers with strings.
Besides answering direct commands, it also constantly puts out data as strings.
I'd like to have this device control in just one thread for writing commands to the socket and reading data from the socket.

Sometimes, the device does not put out data. So a blocking read() on my socket to the device would block the aformentioned thread.
In this case, I would not be able to send a command to the device, because the thread is blocked in read().

I started using SocketChannel, because I can set this type of communication to ***non blocking*** mode.
Now, this works fine except the fact that in my loop to poll data with read(), the system load increases dramatically because of the polling loop is apparently stressing the system.
I find it not very elegant to put a thread sleep after every read() operation in order to keep the system load low.

I also found out that I could set a ***SO_TIMEOUT*** value for the read() on plain Socket Objects. But by using this, I would have to use the thrown timeout exception as normal program flow which in my view is not very elegant, neither... Especially because it is a normal condition in this application to be able to listen to answers from the device and simultaniously sending commands.

What would be the best approach for the task? Is there another opportunity I havn't figured out, yet?

Thanks,
Maik

Comment: Have you looked at the Selector API? That would at least avoid the spinning loop that you have with the SocketChannel configured non-blocking.

Comment: Would you reccomend it for just the one client/server connection I'm servicing? Yes, I have looked at it (and forgotten to mention it in my original question, thanks for bringing it up). I will look deeper into it, now that you suggested that way. My only fear concerning the Selector API was that I'm using a sledge hammer for cracking the nut and just don't see the "simple" solution. Thanks so far for the answer!

Comment: I checked the Selector API and observed that the System load is increasing when I'm in the while loop that is doing non blocking reads and writes on my SocketChannel. I could reduce system load by putting a Thread.sleep() into the while loop but that is exactly what I wanted to avoid.
It looks like that is not the correct way of doing what I intend to do.
Another idea would be to have 2 threads on a socket: One for reads and one for writes. So as long as the read thread blocks, because there is no data, I could still send data to the device via the write thread. Is this a senseful approach?

Comment: The Selector API is a simple API to use so it's possible you don't have something right, maybe you don't clear the selected-key set, that would mean the thread does not block in select.